# Remove/hide a specify category-name from the url

Tags: permalinks, urls, htaccess

I have several categories post:

```
General
News
Comedy
Competitions
Culture
Gaming
Food
etc
```

The posts url are in the following format:

```
www.mydomain.com/category-name/post-title
```

Example:

```
www.mydomain.com/food/how-to-make-paella
www.mydomain.com/gaming/game-of-theday
```

But I would like to hide from the URL the category name 'general' so for example.

instead of

```
www.mydomain.com/general/how-to-learn-spanish
```

have

```
www.mydomain.com/how-to-learn-spanish
```

I have tried some wiring a rewrite rule in the .htaccess but doesn't work.

Any idea how can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use post name in your permalinks setting.
And for Category Base and Tag Base make it blank

Hope this will help

Comment: Hi @Aftab Alam I can do that but I want to show the category name in the URL except for only one category. Doing that all category names will not displayed in the URL.  --Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following Rewrite rule in your .htaccess ?

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ http://YOUR_SITE_NAME/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi @JItendra Rana yes, I have tried that one, but doesn't work :(  --Thanks

Comment: You could try out Yoast seo plugin. It has option to remove category from permalink.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired URL structure where the category name is hidden for the "General" category, you can use the following `.htaccess` rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    
    # Exclude the 'general' category from the URL
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/general/
    
    # Rewrite the URL for posts in other categories
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /$1/$2 [L]
    
    # Rewrite the URL for posts in the 'general' category
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /general/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```